# Dealing with "Don't know" and "missing" in the outcome variable

Tags: logistic, missing-data, biostatistics, regression-strategies

I want to use a generalized linear model for my analysis but the problem I am facing is that the outcome variable y which is categorical is not binomial since I have the following responses: Yes, No, dont know and missing thus I cant run a GLM.

How should I deal with "dont know" and "missing" so the outcome variable will only be yes or no? any suggestions

Comment: What's the problem with multinominal?

Comment: but I need odds ratios to answer my research question

Comment: Multinominal estimates several logistic regression for u

Comment: Either follow Student T's suggestion using a multinominal model, or make some assumption about the 'don't know' category (such as worse/best case scenarios, where you recode them to either the Yes or No category), **and** using replacement techniques (e.g. multiple imputation) for the missing responses.

Comment: Thank you guys. I will discuss this with my supervisors but as I know imputation will lead to some bias in my results.

Comment: Why do you have missing? Structural missing, or missing answers?  How large proportion of don't know? I would think about using ( ultiple) imputation, but that depends on how you answer those Qs!

Comment: I am working on Nigeria DHS, 2013, my outcome variable is wether U5 children have diarrhea or no. The missing and dont know are part of the respondents answer to the question whether your child have diarrhea or no. The data is as follow: Total popualtion N= 18683, No= 16710, yes= 2340, don know = 105 and missing= 68.

Comment: Well, the reason to using imputation is usually that it *reduces* bias! (but it would be optimistic to expect to eliminate it)